# django python code doesn't return the object I expected

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, one-to-one

I'm following the example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Can anyone please help explain why at the lines below doesn't return `Restaurant: Ace Hardware the restaurant`? Instead, it returns `Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant`. Thanks.

```
>>> r
<Restaurant: Ace Hardware the restaurant>
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Ace Hardware the restaurant>

# Set the place back again, using assignment in the reverse direction:

>>> p1.restaurant = r
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>
```

The code and actual output is as below:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name


>>> p1 = Place(name='Demon Dogs', address='944 W. Fullerton')
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Place(name='Ace Hardware', address='1013 N. Ashland')
>>> p2.save()
>>> r = Restaurant(place=p1, serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
>>> r.save()
>>> r.place
<Place: Demon Dogs the place>
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>

>>> r.place = p2
>>> r.save()
>>> r.place
<Place: Ace Hardware the place>
>>> p2.restaurant
<Restaurant: Ace Hardware the restaurant>
>>> r
<Restaurant: Ace Hardware the restaurant>
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Ace Hardware the restaurant>
>>> r.place
<Place: Ace Hardware the place>

>>> p1.restaurant = r
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>
```

Comment: There is no 2nd restaurant. There is only one restaurant (a hot dog shop) and it keeps moving from one place to the other. Since it is a one-to-one relation that restaurant (`r`) can have exactly one associated place. By setting `p1.restaurant` to `r` you practically change its address to `p1` (which is "Demon Dogs").

Comment: I think I have already answered your question but feel free to ask for clarification.